# Mongoose: MongoError won't prevent pre hooks to run?

Tags: mongoose, middleware, mongoose-schema

I'm using Mocha to make some tests in my API and I noticed that when I have a field with `unique: true` and I make the tests on a duplicate field, all of my `pre('save')` still are called. Am I doing something wrong?

user.js

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function test(next) {
  console.log(123);
});
```

test.js

```
var user1 = await User.findOne({ email: "test@test.com" });
var user2 = new User({ email: "test@test.com" });
await user2.save()
```

console:

```
123
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection (...)
```

[Here](https://prnt.sc/26dqoyv) there is an image of my test. In the "creates a new document when valid" I create two new users. In the "email is unique ..." test, I try to create another with the same email as I created before. The "1234567" are console.log I put inside my pre hook.

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923043/mongoose-uniquetrue-pre-save-hook-calls-hook-before-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I discovered how things work with unique and pre hooks.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582862/mongoose-pre-save-async-middleware-not-working-as-expected) is the best way to fix this kind of problem.

Edit: some details for this answer as Tyler appointed that it could become invalid.

In my case, my pre saves have crucial logic with relationships. So when I was trying to save an invalid document, all the relationships of it were being associated with a wrong document.

Since async pre hooks are called all together, I had to garantee that my unique validation was called before everything. Using `.path('field').validate` was the best way I found so far to do it, since it is called even before `.pre('validate')`. Here is my code:

```js
UserSchema.path('email').validate(async function validateDuplicatedEmail(value) {
    if (!this.isNew && !this.isModified('email')) return true;

    try {
        const User = mongoose.model("User");

        const count = await User.countDocuments({ email: value });
        if (count > 0) return false;

        return true;
    }
    catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}, "Email already exists");
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Agreed, updated my answer.